# For in FLOWR in XQuery

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xquery

When we execute:

```html
let $country := doc("file.xml")/mondial/country
for $co in $country
for $c in $co/province
let $count := count($co/province/city)
where $count > 40
return(<country name="{($co/name)}">{($count)}</country>)
```

We get

```html
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="Spain">65</country>
<country name="Spain">65</country>
<country name="Spain">65</country>
<country name="Spain">65</country>
```

But we only want to return one country and its `$count`, like this;

```html
<country name="France">41</country>
<country name="Spain">65</country>
```

We believe that the problem is in "for".

How do we return one unique row and skip multiple ones?

Comment:

A small XML input sample,

```html
 <country car_code="E"
            area="504750"
            capital="cty-Spain-Madrid"
            memberships="org-AfDB org-CAN ">
      <name>Spain</name>
      <localname>el Reino de España</localname>
      <population year="1991" measured="census">38871331</population>
      <population measured="census" year="2001">40847371</population>
      <population measured="census" year="2011">46815916</population>
      <population_growth>0.78</population_growth>
      <infant_mortality>2.7</infant_mortality>
      <gdp_total>1356000</gdp_total>
      <gdp_agri>3.1</gdp_agri>
      <gdp_ind>26</gdp_ind>
      <gdp_serv>70.8</gdp_serv>
      <inflation>1.8</inflation>
      <unemployment>26.3</unemployment>
      <indep_date>1492-01-01</indep_date>
      <government>parliamentary monarchy</government>
      <encompassed continent="europe" percentage="100"/>
      <ethnicgroup percentage="100">Mediterranean Nordic</ethnicgroup>
      <religion percentage="68">Roman Catholic</religion>
      <religion percentage="4.1">Muslim</religion>
      <religion percentage="0.3">Protestant</religion>
      <religion percentage="0.25">Jehovas Witnesses</religion>
      <language percentage="74">Spanish</language>
      <language percentage="19">Catalan</language>
      <language percentage="5">Galician</language>
      <language percentage="2">Basque</language>
      <border country="AND" length="65"/>
      <border country="F" length="623"/>
      <border country="GBZ" length="1.2"/>
      <border country="P" length="1214"/>
      <province id="prov-Spain-2" country="E" capital="cty-Spain-5">
         <name>Andalucía</name>
         <area>87585</area>
         <population measured="census" year="1991">6940105</population>
         <population year="1994">7053043</population>
         <population measured="census" year="2001">7357558</population>
         <population measured="census" year="2011">8371271</population>
         <city id="cty-Spain-5" country="E" province="prov-Spain-2">
            <name>Sevilla</name>
            <name>Seville</name>
            <latitude>37.38</latitude>
            <longitude>-5.99</longitude>
            <elevation>12</elevation>
            <population year="1991" measured="census">701927</population>
            <population year="1994">714148</population>
            <population year="2001" measured="census">684633</population>
            <population year="2011" measured="census">698042</population>
            <located_at watertype="river" river="river-Guadalquivir"/>
         </city>
         <city id="cty-Spain-34" country="E" province="prov-Spain-2">
            <name>Almería</name>
            <latitude>36.84</latitude>
            <longitude>-2.47</longitude>
            <elevation>27</elevation>
            <population year="1991" measured="census">168025</population>
            <population year="1994">167361</population>
            <population year="2001" measured="census">166328</population>
            <population year="2011" measured="census">189680</population>
            <located_at watertype="sea" sea="sea-Mittelmeer"/>
         </city>
         <city id="cty-Spain-39" country="E" province="prov-Spain-2">
            <name>Cádiz</name>
            <latitude>36.53</latitude>
            <longitude>-6.28</longitude>
            <elevation>11</elevation>
            <population year="1991" measured="census">143129</population>
            <population year="1994">155438</population>
            <population year="2001" measured="census">133363</population>
            <population year="2011" measured="census">124014</population>
            <located_at watertype="sea" sea="sea-Atlantic"/>
         </city>
         <city id="cty-Spain-13" country="E" province="prov-Spain-2">
            <name>Córdoba</name>
            <latitude>37.88</latitude>
            <longitude>-4.77</longitude>
            <elevation>120</elevation>
            <population year="1991" measured="census">309961</population>
            <population year="1994">315948</population>
            <population year="2001" measured="census">308072</population>
            <population year="2011" measured="census">328326</population>
            <located_at watertype="river" river="river-Guadalquivir"/>
         </city>
         <city id="cty-Spain-16" country="E" province="prov-Spain-2">
            <name>Granada</name>
            <latitude>37.18</latitude>
            <longitude>-3.6</longitude>
            <elevation>738</elevation>
            <population year="1991" measured="census">241471</population>
            <population year="1994">271180</population>
            <population year="2001" measured="census">240661</population>
            <population year="2011" measured="census">241003</population>
         </city>
```

Our input file is very large, and it is kinda hard to copy it all in here. But this is a very small sample, of Spain, in one province. We have a xml file for all countries, provinces and cities. So imagine multiple kind of xml input sample, but for other countries and cities.

Basically, we count how many cities every country has and return the number in  return, with the name of the country. But we get multiple rows which is the same.

Comment: can you check with this return statement with distinct-values: `return (distinct-values(<country name="{($co/name)}">{($count)}</country>))`

Comment: It only returns numbers, multiple ones, not unique ones.

Comment: Please share sample actual input change your data and keep your tags proper then it will help me to understand structure.

Comment: Your suggestion returns, 41
41
41
41
41
41
41
41
41
41
41
41
41
65
65
65
65
65

Comment: Please edit your question and show a small but representative XML input sample. Also tell us whether you use XQuery 1 or 3 as any grouping is easier in XQuery 3.

Comment: Please check out code again.

Comment: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yo check this link if it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, assuming there is only one `country` element for each country in the world, you just have to eliminate one `for` subexpression (which you don't seem to use anyway):

```
let $country := doc("file.xml")/mondial/country
for $co in $country
let $count := count($co/province/city)
where $count > 40
return <country name="{($co/name)}">{($count)}</country>
```